# Respuesta no legible AJAX jQuery PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Tengo una parte de código con jQuery que hace una llamada a una URL externa de la que recibe información, en un servidor de producción. Lo cierto es que en el servidor de desarrollo tengo el mismo código y lo el resultado es correcto. 
Un ejemplo de su salida es esta:

PR01: {Num: "077631", LgAdr1: "LAVERIE DU SOLEIL", LgAdr2: "", LgAdr3: "322 AVE CHARLES DE GAULLE", LgAdr4: "", …}
PR02: {Num: "001048", LgAdr1: "LE JARDIN DES 3 FRERES", LgAdr2: "", LgAdr3: "47 AVENUE DE RASCASSA", LgAdr4: "", …}
PR03: {Num: "007468", LgAdr1: "PASIBETE", LgAdr2: "", LgAdr3: "1722 AVENUE MAJORAL JOUVE", LgAdr4: "", …

Pero en el servidor de producción la salida que tengo por consola no la muestra bien codificada:

��)�<9K����6^HK�ag8����b"M#)��}5&c�9��Ԃf��DZ,�2���Ǒ��Ԅ�R2H�X�Uyx�������S�u�����#��3B,&�Q���������5V@-��K��2����Q����Y�F�n�-t�f���է��V�#A���qht�ۦ������l��U���3��(�>%f�0�T��4�L��س��c�u�L{��L)�c��Cl�/����9 ��pȸd`ku�?��G���F#)��}�5&c�9��Ԃf��DZ,�2���Ǒ��Ԅ�R2H�X�Uy�r�bq�0�z�|߈�>����q�#�X'�Ɉ��x�mQ���ovq/

La parte del código es:

```
$.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: _PS_MR_MODULE_DIR_ + 'ajax.php',
                data: {'method' : 'MRGetRelayPoint',
                    'id_carrier' : carrier_id,
                    'ajax' : true,
                    'step' : 2,
                    'mrtoken' : mrtoken},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json)
                {
                    if (json && json.error && json.error.length)
                        PS_MRDisplayErrorRelayPoint(json.error, $('#PS_MRSelectedCarrier_' + carrier_id));
                    else if (json && json.success)
                        PS_MRDisplayRelayPoint(json, $('#PS_MRSelectedCarrier_' + carrier_id), carrier_id);
                    for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(json)){
                            console.log(key,value); 
                        }
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    // Put debug to see error detail
                    console.log('error: ' + thrownError);
                    console.log('response: ' + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

El metodo al que llama está revisado y debe funcionar correctamente. Hace cosa de un mes tubimos que hacer una muigración del servidor de producción. Si en el servidor de desarrollo está funcionando el mismo código no se si el problema está en el mismo.

Gracias de antemano!